# Exact match for word in list of words for each column

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
word   sentence  
cat    the cat was red
blue   the cat was red
dog    the dogs
```

I'd like to add a new column of 0 or 1 depending on whether word has an exact match in sentence, i.e.

```
word   sentence          isInSentence
cat    the cat was red        1
blue   the cat was red        0
dog    the dogs               0
```

I found that match function that can do this for a word in a vector of strings. However, when I apply match directly

```
 ifelse(match(d$word, strsplit(d$sentence, ' '), nomatch=0) == 0, 0, 1)
```

it doesn't work as expected. I think that it's not performing the match operation by rows, as I would like. I've also looked into grep, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to get either function to do what I would like.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `str_detect` from `stringr` to check if the 'word' is in the 'sentence'.  To prevent substring matching, we can `paste` word boundary (`\\b`) at the start and end of the 'word'

```
library(stringr)
d$isInSentence <-  as.integer(str_detect(d$sentence, paste0("\\b", d$word, "\\b")))
d$isInSentence
#[1] 1 0 0
```

---

In the OP's code, the `strsplit` returns a `list`.  So, we need to loop through the corresponding `list` elements with that of 'word'.  For this, `Map/mapply` can be used.  For no matches, by default we get NA.  So, it can be converted to `logical` with `is.na` and then coerce to integer with `as.integer`

```
as.integer(!is.na(mapply(match, d$word, strsplit(d$sentence, ' '))))
#[1] 1 0 0
```